# To loop after using explode function in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to loop data into a database after splitting a string using the explode function.. there seems to be some errors in my code but being a beginner, I just cant seem to find it at the moment.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Once this works, I would have to include 3 more values to the same loop. An example of putting another value to loop in the same code would be appreciated..

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("cmsd", $con);
$pieces = explode(" ", $_POST['fname']);
$number = count($pieces); 
echo $number;
for ($i=0; $i<=$number; $i++) {
    $itno = $pieces[$i]; 
    $sql="INSERT INTO nametable (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('$itno', $_POST['lname'])";
}
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($con)
```

Comment: Whats the error you're getting?

Comment: pls post the errors , otherwise we will not able to help you properly

Comment: @zaf Right now the error is  **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\cmsd\insert.php on line 37**

Comment: You're wonderfully open to SQL Injection, look into parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create on more for loop for another variable like this.And also in for loop check for only `$i<$number` and not `$i<=$number` because , if size of array is 5 then you are trying to get 6th value from array which will show error to you.

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("cmsd", $con);
$pieces = explode(" ", $_POST['fname']);
$pieces2 = explode(" ", $_POST['sname']);
$number = count($pieces); 
$number2 = count($pieces2); 
echo $number;
for ($i=0; $i<$number; $i++) {
for ($j=0; $j<$number; $j++) {
    $itno = $pieces[$i]; 
    sql="INSERT INTO nametable (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('".$itno."', '".$_POST['lname']."')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
         die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
     }
     else
          echo "1 record added";
}
}
mysql_close($con)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `mysql_query($sql,$con)` statement inside for loop otherwise only the last value in $pieces is inserted as it keeps getting overwritten inside for loop without insertion being done.

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("cmsd", $con);
$pieces = explode(" ", $_POST['fname']);
$number = count($pieces); 
echo $number;
for ($i=0; $i<=$number; $i++) {
    $itno = $pieces[$i]; 
    $sql="INSERT INTO nametable (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('$itno', $_POST['lname'])";
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

}
echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: error on this line **$sql="INSERT INTO nametable (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('$itno', $_POST['lname'])";** .. same error as everyone else **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\cmsd\insert.php on line 16**

Comment: change that error line to `$sql="INSERT INTO nametable (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('".$itno."', '".$_POST['lname']."')";`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<body>





<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

if (!$con)

  {

  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

  }



mysql_select_db("cmsd", $con);

 $pieces = explode(" ", $_POST['fname']);
 $number = count($pieces); 
 echo $number;
 for ($i=0; $i<=$number; $i++)
 {
 $itno = $pieces[$i]; 


$sql="INSERT INTO nametable (firstname, lastname)

VALUES

('$itno', $_POST['lname'])";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

  {

  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }

echo "1 record added";

 }





mysql_close($con)

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: error **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\cmsd\insert.php on line 25**